# Hibernate foreign key constraint

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a Hibernate Class with the foreign key constraint on it properly defined. Unfortunately the corresponding DB table , do not have the constraints imposed from the hibernate class. Hibernate was not following the constraint restriction. My question here is for hibernate to work. Is it required always to  DB constraints + hibernate constraints to go hand in hand?

Comment: what DB are you using?

Comment: Is the database schema generated from the Hibernate annotations? How? Regarding your question: no, Hibernate doesn't care about database constraints. If they exist and you violate one, you'll get an exception. If they don't exist, you won't get any exception, but you might of course corrupt the database.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. So in my case , I see the constraints in Hibernate class and don't see in DB table I am using. So updating the constraints, making the functionality work properly.

Comment: The foreign key constraints defined in your mapping are only used when you use Hibernate to generate the database schema. If you don't, they are useless.

Comment: @JBNizet That explains everything. Thanks for the information.